# Answer will become correct in the future. Should I accept it?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, specific-question

[Check whether update_batch() is successful in CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10398907/check-whether-update-batch-is-successful-in-codeigniter)

The answer to my CMS-related question was something I've tried and didn't help. However, looking at the Git repo for the CMS, I discovered the answer WILL work as soon as the version that's currently in development becomes stable.

Do I:

1. Take into consideration that the answer wasn't useful to me in my specific case, edit my question so that it specifically refers to the current version and not accept the answer?
2. Edit or ask the user to edit his answer so that it takes note of this version-specific caveat, and then accept it since this is how other users would find it useful in the future?

Answer (score 3):

You should not edit your question to make it match the answer being given, especially if there are other answers that would not be anymore valid, once you edit your question.

You could accept the answer you are referring, if that helped you; this doesn't mean it gave you the correct solution, but it pointed you to the correct solution.

You can ask the user to add a note about the specific version you are asking for, but you should not edit the answer to add that note yourself. If it's not something the user said in a  comment for his answer, you should not add to an answer something the user didn't say; adding links to the documentation, or relevant external sites is fine, but not to alter the answer to add something you say.

Comment: Not editing my question to fit the answer or editing the answer duly noted. I guess I won't accept the answer just yet, since it wasn't actually useful to me at the moment. I'm tempted to answer my own question saying that what I wanted to do wasn't possible with the current version of the CMS, but it would be possible in a later version (I'd cite that original answer as well, of course). You think that's the way to go?